# How can I have different rows in a fixed number of sections?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am having trouble and can't figure out how I can have a different number of rows in each sections of a TableViewController. Moreover, could you show me how I can access them ?

I don't understand how it is supposed to work if I have to set array.count in

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

Comment: Structure your data in an array of arrays.  The main array has one sub-array per section and the sub-arrays have your cell information.

Answer (score 1):

Say the model for a cell is simply an int. You could make your table view's model be an array of arrays. Use the outer array to hold sections, and the inner array to hold the rows of a section:

```
let model: [[Int]] = [
    [1, 2, 3],              //First section, 3 rows
    [4],                    //2nd section, 1 row
    [5, 6, 7, 8],           //3rd section, 4 rows
    [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] //4th section, 6 rows
]
```

And then as Frankenstein says in his answer:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return model[section].count
}

override func numberOfSections( in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return model.count
}
```

And your cellForRowAt function would use the section number as the index into the outer array, and the row as the index into the inner array:

```
let item = model[section][row]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `two-dimensional` array for this purpose, like this:

```
var array = [[MyType]]()
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    array[section].count
}
```